# How to send existing params to token endpoint using custom provider with NextAuth.js in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a custom provider configured in NextAuth.js.

I currently have the following provider config:

```
{
      id: "myauth",
      name: "myauthname",
      type: "oauth",
      clientId: "nextjs-client",
      clientSecret: "dummy-secret",
      authorization: {
        url: "http://localhost:8087/token-mediator/oauth/authorize",
        params: { scope: "openid email profile" }
       },

       
      token: {
        url: "http://localhost:8087/token-mediator/oauth/token"
      }
```

I want to pass `code` query param value that comes back from a redirect to my Nextjs app using NextAuth.js to the token endpoint after user logs-in to a oauth server.  For example I get this from a redirect once the user logs-in:

```
http://localhost:3001/api/auth/callback/myauth?code=somevalue
```

Now, I want to forward that query param's `code` value to my token endpoint.  Any clues on how to do this?

How do I do that?

Thanks